# Classification of Lie algebras.

Tags: lie-algebras

My question iv very obvious: There are how many Lie algebras of dimension $3$ up to isomorphism?

I studied many texts but not getting a single word answer, plesae tell me about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are uncountably many 3-dimensional real Lie algebras. See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification#Dimension_3).

See also the [discussion on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/165656/how-many-three-dimensional-real-lie-algebras-are-there).

There is also a recent PhD thesis on the subject: [Allegra Fowler-Wright, *The Classification of Three-dimensional Lie Algebras*, Thesis Submitted to The University of Warwick (2014)](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/research/y4_fowlerwright.pdf)